# How to decode BLOB data object from session table CI

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session

I am creating a REST API to use with my android app, so I enable CodeIgniter database session manager (i followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34622330/codeigniter-3-0-3-ci-session-not-saving-session-data-to-ci-sesstion-table)), to store some information from my users when they log in.

Here is my code to store information:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('key', 'value');
```

Here is my config.php:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = TRUE;
```

My question is: How can i get the information i already stored on session table? I only see a BLOB object on the columns ci_session but how can I decode it or how is it used?

I already sent the session Id from my server to my android app and whenever my app needs information from the server it sends it back. I also created the select query to get the BLOB object:

```
$data = $this->db->query("SELECT data FROM ci_sessions WHERE id='5c825c032b6cf25b10e984f0ee8e1bd48a2c1916'");
    $query = $data->result();
```

But how do I access the key of the data to get the value?

Comment: Check an answer to a similar question
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51103875/1214244

Answer (score 1):

CodeIgniter already does that for you, if you want an array for the whole set of items:

```
$this->session->all_userdata()
```

That would return all key and values, if you just want to grab a specific value then:

```
$this->session->userdata('foo');
```

Where `foo` is the key of the value you want to retrieve.

It works exactly as [it is on the documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html) the only difference is that the session data is stored in a database instead of being handled by PHP / Webserver. So to store or access the data just use the usual methods. You don't have to query the database directly for session information.

**Update:**

Also make sure that you load the sessions library first by means of loading it in your controller first, in the constructor:

```
public function __construct() 
{
  $this->load->library('session');
}
```

Or by [autoloading the library](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/autoloader.html) (which I'd rather recommend)

Comment: Then how does CodeIgniter knows which session data to retrieve? is it really necessary to send back my session id from my android app to the server?

Comment: REST is stateless and so is HTTP. You can't have a REST API and try to make it behave like a browser session, therefore, you need to be querying for the session. Have you considered using tokens instead?

Comment: How should i use tokens? So, there is no wey to work with BLOB object?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver but again, you should not rely on the sessions table to query the blob object, that is managed by codeigniter internally.